# Make ckeditor read only on page load

Tags: html, ckeditor, readonly

I want to make ckeditor read-only on a page, and only read-only. How do I do this? I have tried to reform the below code to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I made the editor to have a toggle read-only mode, which loads as not read-only. (It's not but I want, but this is the closest I have gotten) This is the code I have for that:

```
window.onload = function () {
    CKEDITOR.replace('textBox', );
}

var editor;

// The instanceReady event is fired, when an instance of CKEditor has finished
// its initialization.
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    editor = ev.editor;

    // Show this "on" button.
    document.getElementById('readOnlyOn').style.display = '';

    // Event fired when the readOnly property changes.
    editor.on('readOnly', function () {
        document.getElementById('readOnlyOn').style.display = this.readOnly ? 'none' : '';
        document.getElementById('readOnlyOff').style.display = this.readOnly ? '' : 'none';
    });
});

function toggleReadOnly(isReadOnly) {
    // Change the read-only state of the editor.
    // http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setReadOnly
    editor.setReadOnly(isReadOnly);
}
```

And the *html*:

```
 <p>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1" name="editor1" style="height:400px;width:900px">${alert.html}</textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input id="readOnlyOn" onclick="toggleReadOnly();" type="button" value="Make it read-only"
    style="display:none" />
    <input id="readOnlyOff" onclick="toggleReadOnly( false );" type="button"
    value="Make it editable again" style="display:none" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define `disabled` attribute for `<textarea>` and the editor will start read-only:

```
<textarea id="editor" disabled>Cow says moo!</textarea>
```

See [the sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdXvg/).

Comment: But can it do issue when form is posted? In normal controls, if the input is disabled, values are not submitted while on readonly, they will be readonly but values will be submitted.